# How to use windows task scheduler to run updatedb?

Tags: command-line, sudo, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "sudo updatedb"
```

from a (privileged, if needed) windows command line, I get a prompt for sudo password.

Having `ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate -D` in /etc/sudoers does not make a difference.

I can run `sudo updatedb` without a password prompt from within bash itself, regardless of the line above in sudoers.

Running without sudo yields the standard and expected `updatedb: can not open a temporary file for '/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db'`

**I would like to find a windows cmd line that works so I can put updatedb in a scheduled task. If sudoers need to be modified, fine.**

Comment: If you need a Windows cmd line, that would be a question for [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a private computer and have no security issue regarding password protection, you could use the following workaround :

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "echo 'my_password' | sudo -S updatedb"
```

The `-S` flag means sudo will read the password from stdin. The obvious issue is that you have to explicitely write your password in your command, which isn't really safe.

EDIT:

As a sidenote, I've added the following line at the end of my /etc/sudoers file :

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get*
```

Afterward, runing `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "sudo apt-get update"` from cmd.exe worked flawlessly. Did you make sure your rule wasn't overwriten ? If there is a permission conflict in your sudoers file, bash will use the last rule written. Make sure you put your `ALL ALL=NOPASSWD:` line at the end of the file.

Comment: The top suggestion worked, but after adding an * to the end of the line in sudoers it also works the original way I was trying. Thank you. –